# How is best way to create line with :after but with circle at end?

Tags: css, line, border, arrows

[image]

So, how can i create those line's after those elemets (Tomatos...etc) but i also need circle at end of each line?

I tried this way but without circle because i cant find any way!:

```
.h1:after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 0.5em;
width: 95px;
margin-top: 13px;
border-top: 2px solid black;
margin-left: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a circle by setting some border styling with the ::before element.
You size the circle by setting the border height (here 10px) and make it completely round setting the radius to 50%. You can position it using top/left properties.

```
.h1::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid black;
    left: 293px;
    top: 24px;
}
```